# Windows Store app 8.1 Xaml pausing/resuming download using http classes

Tags: download, windows-store-apps, resume

I'm trying to use http classes to pause/resume a download and pausing is easy by using the cancellation token , however how can i resume a download?

I have used the background downloader class and it had a lot of issues in resuming and had many other issues to handle downloads.

Here is my code:

```
 using Windows.Web.Http;
 using Windows.Web.Http.Filters;

private async void Foo(StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
{

Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost");
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ServerCredential =
    new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(uri.ToString(), "foo", "bar");
var client = new HttpClient(filter);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-");

// Hook up progress handler.
Progress<HttpProgress> progressCallback = new Progress<HttpProgress>(OnSendRequestProgress);
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(tokenSource.Token, progressCallback);

IInputStream inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

// Copy from stream to stream.
IOutputStream outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);
}

private void OnSendRequestProgress(HttpProgress obj)
{
 Debug.WriteLine(obj);
 }
```

Comment: I have a feeling what you may need to do is to save off the current position of the download when it gets cancelled, then when resuming you can `Seek` the `Stream` to that position. Your file server will likely have to have a resume function (which it seems it does with your `"Range"` header).

Comment: @NateDiamond i got the idea but how do i do it in windows store app, which classes should i use for seeking a stream, they are a little different than of those of .net

Comment: It turns out it's actually a bit easier than that. `StorageFile.OpenAsync` returns an `IRandomAccessStream`, which has a method `GetOutputStreamAt(long)`. The `long` parameter there is the file offset! So all you need to do is pass in the current byte that you want and it should automatically seek to that point in the file stream, so you can continue writing from where you left off.

Comment: @NateDiamond cancelling the download using the cancel token makes the IRandomAccessStream null and gives an exception, so the problem is writing the file before pausing

Comment: @NateDiamond sorry i have a problem implementing it, can you help?

Comment: I think you should try and use the `BackgroundDownloader`. It was designed exactly for this and supports pause/resume. What problems were you having with that?

Comment: @NateDiamond when i ever i pause a download then resume it, it restarts, i tried also normal downloads without headers that supports resuming and i had the same issue!

Comment: even i have downloaded sample codes and haven't edited anything and also i face the same issue.

Comment: Are you making sure to store off the `DownloadOperation`? If you don't, you can't pause/resume.

Comment: @NateDiamond i'm evening making a more simple scenario i just pause and immediately resume the download.

Comment: try this sample code your self and you will find there are problems in resuming...
http://eren.ws/2013/10/08/how-to-download-and-save-files-in-a-windows-store-app-using-httpwebrequest-boredom-challenge-day-4/

Comment: That guide doesn't cover resuming, [this one by the same author does](http://eren.ws/2013/10/10/downloading-files-with-backgrounddownloader-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-6/).

Comment: ohh sorry i have posted the wrong link...i meant the one you just posted now...did you try it?